# nodemon not working: -bash: nodemon: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, express, npm, nodemon

I'm on a Mac running El Capitan. I have node v5.6.0 and npm v3.6.0. 
When I try to run nodemon, I get:

```
-bash: nodemon: command not found
```

I thought this may mean that I didn't have nodemon installed, so when I tried to install it using...

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

...I get this:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"     "nodemon"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/nodemon
npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/nodemon: ../lib/node_modules/nodemon/nodemon.js symlink target is not controlled by         npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/nodemon
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/brianeoneill/npm-debug.log
```

If it makes a difference, I'm trying to run nodemon on a project that uses Express v4.13.1

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Have you uninstalled nodemon before trying to install it again globally? `npm uninstall nodemon`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. However, I just tried sudo npm install -g --force nodemon, and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your help!!!!!

Comment: May be my solution helps you ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505121/bash-nodemon-command-not-found-windows-10/46507487#46507487

Answer (score 262):

I tried the following, and none worked:

```
npm uninstall nodemon

sudo npm uninstall -g nodemon
```

What did work was:

```
sudo npm install -g --force nodemon
```

Comment: watch the following video from official docs site https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions . Will give you better insight about the issue.

Comment: recommendation to delete package : 
1 - Remove line from package.json 
2 - and type this command " node prone "

Answer (score 127):

If you want to run it locally instead of globally, you can run it from your node_modules:

> npx nodemon

Comment: EDIT: sadly i have to use this command each and everytime i want to run my program instead of it installing nodemon locally.

Comment: This works on Mac OSx like charm! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! For anyone having to run it manually every time, just add a new script in your package.json like so `"serve": "npx nodemon index.js"` and then just run with `npm run serve`

Comment: This makes it a lot easier to uninstall and install with sudo etc. Plus I do not want it globally. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 72):

From you own project.

```
npx nodemon [your-app.js]
```

With a local installation, nodemon will not be available in your system path. Instead, the local installation of nodemon can be run by calling it from within an npm script (such as `npm start`) or using `npx nodemon`.

OR

Create a simple symbolik link

```
ln -s /Users/YourUsername/.npm-global/bin/nodemon /usr/local/bin
```

**ln -s [from: where is you install 'nodemon']  [to: folder where are general module for node]**

node : v12.1.0

npm : 6.9.0

Answer (score 55):

I'm using **macOS/Linux**, the solution that works for me is

```
npx nodemon index.js
```

I have tried every possibility, like uninstalling and installing **nodemon**, installing **nodemon** globally. restart the terminal, but it won't work.

don't try such things to waste your time.

Answer (score 34):

in Windows OS run:

```
npx nodemon server.js
```

or add in package.json config:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon server.js"
  },
...
```

then run:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same exact problem, expect for Windows OS.

For me, running

`npm install -g nodemon --save-dev`

(note the **-g**) worked.

Maybe somebody else who has this problem on Windows will have the same solution.

Comment: --save is no longer needed after npm v5

Answer (score 14):

**FOR WINDOW USERS**

I tried every possible way but nothing worked for me.

What worked was:-
**npx nodemon server**

FOLLOWING WILL BE THE OUTPUT:-
[image]

Answer (score 11):

For mac Users, use **npx nodemon index.js**

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx nodemon index.js"
  },
...


> my-project@1.0.0 start
> npx nodemon index.js

Need to install the following packages:
  nodemon
Ok to proceed? (y) 
[nodemon] 2.0.13
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server Started on Port 8000
```

Answer (score 9):

Install nodemon:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Run server:

```
sudo nodemon server.js
```

Answer (score 8):

For nodemon: not found command 
I tried with many links but was not working then i tried with the below steps it worked fine.

Follow this step it worked for me.

step1 : sudo su

step2 : npm install -g nodemon --save-dev

It is working fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

Next package.json on and

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon app.js"
}
```

Type on terminal (command prompt)

```
npm start
```

Comment: I always add it in package file under start, "start": "nodemon app.js" it works perfect, and great way of using nodemin

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem since I had changed my global path of npm packages before.

#### Here's how I fixed it :

When I installed nodemon using : **`npm install nodemon -g --save`** , my path for the global npm packages was not present in the PATH variable .

**If you just add it to the $PATH variable it will get fixed.**

Edit the **`~/.bashrc`** file in your home folder and add this line :-

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm
```

**Here "npm" is the path to my global npm packages . Replace it with the global path in your system**

Comment: or add this line if you use yarn: export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"

Answer (score 6):

In macOS, 
I fixed this error by installing nodemon globally

```
npm install -g nodemon --save-dev
```

and by adding the npm path to the bash_profile file. First, open bash_profile in nano by using the following command,

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Second, add the following two lines to the bash_profile file (I use comments
   "##" which makes it bash_profile more readable)

```
## npm
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case for those using Windows, you don't need `sudo`

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Node v18.11.0 there is running in 'watch' mode using

```
node --watch
```

which restarts the process when an imported file is changed.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.11.0/

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo su
```

then

```
npm install nodemon
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you own root directory for npm so you don't get any errors when you install global packages without using sudo.

procedures:-
in root directory

```
sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/share/
```

So now with

```
npm i npm -g
```

you get no errors and no use of sudo here.
but **if you still get errors**  confirm node_modules is owned again

`/usr/local/lib/`

and make sure you own everything

`ls -la`

[image]
now

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

will work!

Answer (score 3):

Just writing what did worked for me - (on Windows machine, installing node locally to the project)
if you do not want to install it globally (i.e without -g flag) you have to use

```
npx nodemon app
```

where app is your app.js is your program file to launch.

Answer (score 1):

Following commands worked for me in my case

Open Windows Powershell and Run series of following **Commands**,

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

*Press Y for YES*

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Here you Go.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows git bash, I fixed it by restarting git bash

Answer (score 0):

Put `--exec` arg in `single quotation`.

e.g. I changed `"nodemon --exec yarn build-langs"` to `"nodemon --exec 'yarn build-langs'"` and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I even did, having similar problem:

```
node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index
```

and it worked, but now I see is that the proper way is as in many comments in this section, using

```
npx nodemon index
```

Maybe someone will have some use of my solution, for instance I targeted 'mocha' test node modules on one project directly this way, so while probably not the best solution, it can be of use sometimes.