# bash: nodemon: command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have been using nodemon for past few months now. It's just that today I got this error. I tried uninstalling nodemon and the reinstalled it. I also forced install it. Nothing worked. Whenever I run the nodemon command

```
bash: nodemon: command not found
```

pops up.

There are other answers too and I have looked them all up. They haven't worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530930/nodemon-not-working-bash-nodemon-command-not-found

Comment: @JeremyThille I looked through it, doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodemon not working: -bash: nodemon: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530930/nodemon-not-working-bash-nodemon-command-not-found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced this error once, and in my `package.json`, I updated the `nodemon` location and it worked.

Below code is in my `package.json`

```
"start" : "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js"
```

and then after running `npm start` it works.

Comment: I am looking for a permanent solution. In this case, I will have to edit all the package.json files.

Comment: This is a permanent solution, as you should refer to `nodemon` from your modules, as other people who might do installation using your `package.json` might not have it installed globally.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have nodemon installed globally try to do that.
I had the same issue but after installing it globally whenever I ran the command it work

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This is down to your global variables.

Ensure npm is included in your PATH var and there is no conflicting npm directories

`echo %PATH%`

If it is, get your npm root, Ensure the npm in your global path matches the npm root

`npm root -g`

Navigate there and ensure the "nodemon" file is there. This is where all the npm install -g files are installed.
If not run `npm i nodemon -g` and confirm that it has been added to the npm root folder.

Having all of these boxes ticked will get these globals are working for you again.