# bash: nodemon command not found windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I spent a lot of time looking for a solution, but didn't find anything (with my case) So...
I checked global packages `npm list -g --depth=0` and got
[image]

But when I went to the folder `C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, there was no nodemon 
[image]

I know this question has already existed. Please, help me anyone...

Comment: With the addition of the `npx` command, there's not really a good reason to install these things globally anymore. Install `nodemon` to your project as a devDependency then type `npx nodemon`. The `npx` command will do the same local-first search for the binary that is done by a `script` in your `package.json` when run with `npm run scriptname`. When you have time, you should still add a script in `package.json`, since it documents how `nodemon` is being used in your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution (in my case).

All you need is to add `C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm` and `C:\usr\local` (of course with your file paths npm and local) to System variables **(Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced system settings)**.

And after that restart your PC

[image]

Comment: Do you mean fourth step? There are two separate lines

Comment: Yes fourth step, when I edit path, I only got a single line with all entries inside separated by semi colons.

Comment: In third path you need to press on “path” and after that (in fourth path) click on first button “create” and add your full path.

Comment: Also restart PC

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried re-installing nodemon?
`npm i -g nodemon@latest`

If that too does not work, try installing nodemon in your project, dont't save it as dependency though.

Answer (score -3):

Also you may to remove node folder and install nodeJS again