# How to solve "Showing nodemon is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

On running npm start my node js is not starting.
Showing this on `npm start`

> 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I even checked my environment path.

I even ran `npm install -g nodemon` but it is still not working.

Also ran `npm config get prefix` but it is also not working.

Previously I ran this command `npm config set bin-links false`

after that problem started to occur.

Attaching some images for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCTG2.png) : path screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vNBh.png) : screenshot of vs code

Comment: Add `C:\Users\OMR-7\AppData\Roaming\npm` to `path`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: nodemon command not found windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505121/bash-nodemon-command-not-found-windows-10)

Comment: Errors, code, config, etc should be included in the question as formatted text, rather than links to images of formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

If you told npm not to create any links to binaries in packages anymore, it's no surprise that running linked binaries no longer works. (Why did you do that in the first place? Maybe there is a better way to achieve your goal?)

Undo your config change (`npm config set bin-links true`) and reinstall `nodemon`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it worked "silly" mistake.

"npm config set bin-links true"

and ran npm install it worked perfectly.

Previously I ran this command but did not restart vs code so the error was thrown.

Comment: I posted this same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210945/1871033) already. If it solves the problem for you, you can accept ✅ my answer.

Comment: If someone else answered the same, do not write your own answer, instead accept the original answer.