# After I installed nodemon by "npm i nodemon" , when I tried to run it by "nodemon server.js" , it gives me this error. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[Screenshot form VS code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNh0W.png)nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.

Comment: Try installing nodemon globally. Npm install nodemon-g

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodemon not working: -bash: nodemon: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530930/nodemon-not-working-bash-nodemon-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I just meet that question.

**First**, you should make sure that you had installed nodemon in a global way (`npm install -g nodemon`), and make sure global package dir is in the environment variables.

**Secondly**, you should **RESTART** VScode if you are opening it now.
I spent lots of time to make sure the previous one, but it still fails, then when I restart VScode, everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `nodemon` globally:
https://github.com/remy/nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

and edit Your `package.json` for example like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
```

then in terminal enter the command =>

```
npm run dev
```

It should works for You now ;-)
Good Luck and Best regards !

Comment: It should be noted that this should work _without_ needing to install nodemon globally, assuming that nodemon is installed in the package itself.

Answer (score -1):

I just had to use npx instead of npm
for e.g. - npx nodemon <server.js>